# In java Adding up numbers

Tags: java

I want to add up numbers.

(java.numbers)

Comment: So how your output will look like ? And what have you tried for that ?

Comment: Which part of this are you having trouble with, or do you just want the code written for you?

Comment: I want a case of fine Scotch and a paid month off.  This is fun!

Answer (score 1):

you can use slicing

```
a = ("jim", [2,3,4,6])  
sum(a[1][:-1])               only will work if the number in order, else need to use sorted
```

demo:

```
>>> a=("jim", [2,3,4,6])
>>> a[1]
[2, 3, 4, 6]
>>> a[1][:-1]  
[2, 3, 4]
>>> sum(a[1][:-1])     # sum will give sum of element in list
9
>>> print a[0],sum(a[1][:-1])  
jim 9
```

Function:

```
>>> def my_function(*a):       # *a is called splat operator, can catch any number of argument in tuple
...     return a[0],sum(sorted(a[1][:-1]))      #sorted will sort the list, so that largest number goes at end of list, so we can exclude it
... 
>>> my_function("jim", [2,3,4,6])
('jim', 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will do what you are looking for.

```
l = ("jim", [2,3,4,6])
def totalAndDisplay(l):
    l[1].sort()
    print l[0],sum(l[1][:-1])
```

Comment: Among other things, you've redefined the built-in sum function

Comment: This takes a param `l` and then immediately redefines it